# toCompletableFuture() stucks for asynchronous cache

Tags: asynchronous, caching, playframework-2.6

Hello there I am trying to force a promise to end to get the result from it but it just stucks on loading.

```
public class CacheController extends Controller {
    private AsyncCacheApi cache;
    public Result cache()
    {
        String test = "nice";
        cache.set("item.key", test, 15);

        Customer user = new Customer("Ana", 12);
        CompletionStage<Done> result = cache.set(user.getName(), user);
        block(result);

        return ok("Cached");
    }
    public Result checkCache() throws Exception
    {
        Logger.info("start");
        //CompletionStage<String> news = cache.get("item.key");
        //news.thenRun(() -> System.out.println("works"));

        CompletionStage<Customer> result = cache.get("Ana");

        Logger.info("step 1");

        Logger.info(cache.get("Ana").toString());
        Logger.info("Step 2");

        Customer c = block(result);

        Logger.info("Step 3 " + c.getName());

        //result.thenRun(() -> setUser(result)).thenRun(() -> Logger.info(user.getName() + " " + user.getAge()));


        return ok("cancan");
    }

    private <T> T block(CompletionStage<T> stage) {
        try {
            return stage.toCompletableFuture().get();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to load the page it gets stuck after step2 at `line 56: Customer c = block(result);` by my guesses
Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

@Codrin

I had the same problem. But, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaCache#Setting-the-execution-context

> By default, all Ehcache operations are blocking, and async implementations will block threads in the default execution context.

Maybe CompletableFuture.get() gets stuck because it is executed in the same thread with the caller.

Referring to the linked page, I added snippet below to my application.conf and it worked.

```
play.cache.dispatcher = "contexts.blockingCacheDispatcher"

contexts {
blockingCacheDispatcher {
    fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 3.0
    }
  }
}
```